# Foundation 6- disable row flex-flow wrap

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, zurb-foundation-6

I am having problems with grid in **Safari**, and I noticed it is because of the `foundation-flex-grid` and `foundation-flex-classes` that I am including in my `app.scss` file. In the console if I disable the

`flex-flow: row wrap`

Then the grid looks like it should be. Now I am wondering, how can I set this up with a variable in `sass` file, so that the `flex-flow: row wrap` is disabled?